# How to print Greek Characters with python-escpos

Tags: python, encoding, thermal-printer, posprinter, python-escpos

### PART 1

I am currently trying to get my printer to properly output Greek and not GreekLish for my restaurant ordering system.

I am using python-escpos.

**- My code looks like this.**

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
p = Usb(0x471, 0x55, 0, 0x82, 0x2)
p.charcode(code='Greek')
p.text('Καλημέρα \n')
p.cut()
p.close()
```

**- My output looks like this.**

[image: failure 1]

Is there an issue with my string input? Am I supposed to encode it?

Also, The library works currently in shops. The issue is instead of printing, for example, `Καλημερα` I have to print `Kalimera`, greeklish. I need it to look more professional.

Thank you

### PART 2

Added the encoding magic still nothing...

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
from escpos.exceptions import USBNotFoundError
from escpos.magicencode import MagicEncode, Encoder
import requests


resp = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-printer-db/3612db407d02a08acd93a1540f2b4823be3f020e/dist/capabilities.json')
js = resp.json()
encodings = list(js['encodings'].keys())

for encoding in encodings:
    print(encoding)
    try:
        p = Usb(idVendor=0x471, idProduct= 0x55,in_ep=0x82, out_ep=0x02)
        p.magic.force_encoding(encoding)
        p.text(encoding)
        p.text('ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ \n')
            p.cut()
        p.close()
        
    except USBNotFoundError:
        print('printer not connected or on')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**My output looks like this...**

[image: failure #2]

No Greek Goodmorning for me...
I believe I am very close. Any other suggestions?

### PART 3

how about we enter some command in the second `_raw` function?

```
p = Usb(idVendor=0x471, idProduct= 0x55,in_ep=0x82, out_ep=0x02)

ESC = b'\x1b'

p._raw(ESC + b'\x74\x07') # page 28-29 printer manual

p._raw( add something...)  # need to print Καλημερα

p.cut()
p.close()
```

**HELPFULL**

- printer model Alpha TP-80H
- [programmers manual](https://www.elzabhellas.gr/DOWNLOADS/ALFA_TP_80E/EN/POS-80-Series%20Programmer%20Manual.pdf)
- the printer also came with a self-test page.

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Comment: A GitHub issue solved the problem by converting foreign text into an image. I would prefer to figure this out first.

Comment: Why not try using `cp1253` or `iso8859_7` instead of `Greek`? [Magic Encode](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/magicencode.html), [escpos-printer-db/dist/capabilities.json](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-printer-db/blob/3612db407d02a08acd93a1540f2b4823be3f020e/dist/capabilities.json)

Comment: I looped through the capabilities forcing the encodings, it is shown in part 2 of this post. still nothing @kunif.

Comment: For example, why not output it to a file if possible and check if the data content is correct? If that doesn't work, why not put an Issue in the repository? [python-escpos/python-escpos/issues](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/issues)

Comment: Version 2.2.0 installed with `pip install python-escpos` seems to be buggy and unusable. It also doesn't match the documentation. Perhaps it was created for a customized printer from some vendor rather than the standard ESC/POS. Please install and use the latest version under development from the github repository. It seems that you can do it with `p.charcode(code='CP1253')` without using `MagicEncode`. Perhaps the `iconv` command needs to be properly installed and enabled.

Comment: Or, perhaps your printer has different specifications than the standard ESC/POS.

Comment: I am using the python-escpos==3.0a6 and my printer is Alpha tp 80h. And it also provides me with a codepage. Ill add it to my question.

Comment: In the environment of Windows10 Python 3.10.2, based on the first code of the question, when the output destination is `printer.File` and the code is `CP1253`, the following result is obtained in hexadecimal string representation. `1B,74,2F,CA,E1,EB,E7,EC,DD,F1,E1,20,0A,1B,64,06,1D,56,00` These bytes seem appropriate.

Comment: Looking at the results of the self-test page, the code page layout does not meet the EPSON specifications. [ESC t](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32) If it's just about encoding issues, it's probably better to lower the version of python-escpos to 2.2.0 and try it with the first code `Greek` in the question. Alternatively, you may be able to add and specify your printer information to a database that describes the attributes of each company's printer. [escpos-printer-db](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-printer-db)

Comment: It does meet them (EPSON) I just added a missing section of the page, sorry. I also added a programmer's manual for the printer. maybe I can send a custom command with the _raw method. What will that look like?

Comment: It is more versatile and will help others to register and use data that shows the characteristics and attributes of the printer in the database, rather than sending a special custom command. For example, why not create and register this kind of data for your printer? [escpos-printer-db/data/profile/POS-5890.yml](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-printer-db/blob/master/data/profile/POS-5890.yml)

Comment: I will definitely create a profile for them. But, I need a quick solution by using the _raw or something else. Trust me, I will devote a whole blog post to my nightmare and how it was resolved.

Comment: I'm not actually using python-escpos so I don't know what to do with such customization. If you want to try it quickly, why not try the 2.2.0 version mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: ill give it a try with your suggested version. what do you use ? and what would your example look like in code?

Comment: 2.2.0 came in when I installed it on Windows 10 without specifying the version. Looking at the source code, the `Greek` code page had a value of `7`, so I thought it matched the attributes of your printer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the charcode and the codepage

The following code works with my NT-5890K printer

```
p = printer.Usb(0x0416,0x5011, in_ep=0x81, out_ep=0x03)
p.charcode(code='Greek')
p.codepage = 'CP1253''
p.text('Καλημέρα \n')
p.cut()
p.close()
```